# Delete &nbsp; from all elements of the same class

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I was looking for a way to search through all elements of the same class and remove any `&nbsp;` as these were causing unwanted gaps in my page layout.

Initially I used this code:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.offer');
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace('&nbsp;', '');
```

But this only finds the first node with the class of `offer` so isn't much use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I had to piece it together from a number of posts on here as well as other sites and I hope it helps others in my position.

Firstly I needed to use `.queryselectorAll` instead of `.querySelector` to return all elements with the `offer` class.

But the next line wont work since `.queryselectorAll` returns a string of nodes rather than just the first one it comes across.

```
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace('&nbsp;', '');
```

The solution is to loop through each element and replace each instance of `&nbsp;`

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.offer');
for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
  el[i].innerHTML = el[i].innerHTML.replace('&nbsp;', '');
}
```

Comment: Use regex to replace all occurences of the spaces

Comment: could you give me an example of how to use regex for this?

Comment: `str.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, '');`, see [**Regex Explanation and Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/mO4bQ9/1)